# Inheriting System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection<T> in Silverlight library

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is the type `System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection<T>` not intended for inheritance? I was trying to make a custom `<Type>AnimationsFromKeyFrames` object, but I can't create the Collection type for the KeyFrames property because Visual Studio is apparently making up some errors.

Visual Studio reports the following abstract members are not implemented, even though *they don't exist* on any of the inherited objects:

> 'MyKeyFrameCollection' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection<MyKeyFrame>.SetItemImplSkipMethodPack(int, MyKeyFrame)'
>
> 'MyKeyFrameCollection' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection<MyKeyFrame>.GetItemImplSkipMethodPack(int)'
>
> 'MyKeyFrameCollection' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection<MyKeyFrame>.RemoveInternal(MyKeyFrame)'
>
> 'MyKeyFrameCollection' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection<MyKeyFrame>.InsertInternal(int, MyKeyFrame)'
>
> 'MyKeyFrameCollection' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection<MyKeyFrame>.IndexOfInternal(MyKeyFrame)'
>
> 'MyKeyFrameCollection' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection<MyKeyFrame>.ContainsInternal(MyKeyFrame)'
>
> 'MyKeyFrameCollection' does not implement inherited abstract member 'System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection<MyKeyFrame>.AddInternal(MyKeyFrame)'

How do I go about either implementing these methods from bizarro world, or else tell Visual Studio to stop making up gripes and just compile the project?

I've tried explicitly defining these methods using the following which didn't (rightly so, as per previous non-existence remark) work:

```
void System.Windows.PresentationFrameworkCollection<MyKeyFrame>.AddInternal(MyKeyFrame keyFrame)
void System.Collections.Generic.IList<MyKeyFrame>.AddInternal(MyKeyFrame keyFrame)
void System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<MyKeyFrame>.AddInternal(MyKeyFrame keyFrame)
void System.Collections.IList.AddInternal(MyKeyFrame keyFrame)
void System.Collections.ICollection.AddInternal(MyKeyFrame keyFrame)
```

At wit's end, and thinking that MS doesn't want the community making KeyFrameCollections?

**EDIT:** I've tried, and my only `override` options are `Equals`, `GetHashCode`, and `ToString`. Is it possible these abstract members are `protected internal` so that the existing framework classes can inherit from them, but custom classes cannot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PresentationFrameworkCollection` is a public abstract class but the members you are referring to are `internal abstract` which means you can not override them.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I tried getting around it by inheriting from `DependencyObject` and implementing `IList<MyKeyFrame>` similar to how `PresentationFrameworkCollection` works, but now when I try to render I'm met with a COM exception.  Scrapping the whole thing, for now.